# How to concatenate more sql queries to get one table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 4 tables that I have used following queries to get data,

```
query1 : select * from userdetails1.UserTable;

Result1:                
UserID  Username    Status
1         John      Active
2         Micheal   Active
3         Ann       Active
4         Shasha    Resigned
5         mike      Resigned

query2 : select * from userdetails2.AmountTable;

result2:
UserId  TotalAmount TotalAmountResetDate
1          -12         1/31/2022
2          345         1/31/2022
3          213         1/31/2022
4          0           1/31/2022
5          0           1/31/2022

query3:
select Username,TotalInvested from userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable group by Username;

result3:

Username    Totalnvested
John         45000
Micheal      45000
Ann          45000


query4:
select Username,TotalExpenses from userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable group by Username;

Username    TotalExpenses
John           2543
Micheal        2345
Ann            3290
```

Now I need to get another table by combining all these queries as follows. How should I get that by concatenating all these queries?

```
UserId  Username    TotalAmountResetDate    TotalAmount Totalnvested    TotalExpenses   TotalBalance
1        John              1/31/2022               -12       45000            2543          42445
2        Micheal           1/31/2022               345       45000            2345          43000
3        Ann               1/31/2022               213       45000            3290          41923
4        Shasha            1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
5        mike              1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
```

Here `TotalBalance` column need to get from `TotalBalance=TotalAmount+Totalnvested -TotalExpenses`.Is this possible to get using one query?

Update:

If the total expenses and total investments are more than one value we need to get sum of each user to the total investements. Then how we can get that one?

Example:

```
Username    Totalnvested
    John         45000
    Micheal      45000
    Ann          45000
    John         21000
    Micheal       5000


Username    TotalExpenses
John           2543
Micheal        2345
Ann            3290
Ann            2345
John            5478
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subquery for retrieving user name wise total invested and total expense and then use INNER JOIN between user table and amount table and also use LEFT JOIN for invested and expense related result with this for getting desired result. Use aggregate function like SUM() in inside subquery because using group by in given query. If only single row is existed in both invested and expense table then no need to use group by. At this case aggregate function will not use.

```
select t1.UserID
     , t1.Username
     , t2.TotalAmountResetDate
     , t2.TotalAmount
     , t3.TotalInvested
     , t4.TotalExpenses
     , t2.TotalAmount + COALESCE(t3.TotalInvested, 0) - COALESCE(t4.TotalExpenses, 0) TotalBalance 
from userdetails1.UserTable t1
inner join userdetails2.AmountTable t2
        on t1.UserID = t2.UserID
left join (select Username, SUM(TotalInvested) TotalInvested
           from userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable 
           group by Username) t3
       on t1.Username = t3.Username
left join (select Username, SUM(TotalExpenses) TotalExpenses 
           from userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable 
           group by Username) t4
       on t1.Username = t4.Username
```

Comment: I am getting this error. #1305 - FUNCTION userdetails2.colease does not exist

Comment: Please check now @Shehan

Comment: Got an output but the TotalBalance column is wrong. only in first row.Seems when the minus values are getting errors

Comment: TotalAmountResetDate is also wrong, it shows as 0000-00-00

Comment: Here I use your table column. Please provide table structure with sample data

Comment: Now OK..I have another question..If I have these two databases in two different places how should I change this?     As an example userdetails1 in localhost and userdetails2 in 10.62.233.45 server. Then how should this change? Can you update it.

Comment: If two tables are in two server then use linked server. Please study few articles related this if possible or is there any new things.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` to get your expected result.

`OUTER JOIN` need to base on `userdetails1.UserTable` because some people might not have `Investments` or `Expenses` in those tables, then use `COALESCE` function to let `NULL` value be `0`

**Query #1**

```
SELECT t2.UserID,
       t1.Username,
       t2.TotalAmountResetDate,   
       t2.TotalAmount,   
       COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) Totalnvested,
       COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalExpenses,
       t2.TotalAmount + COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) - COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalBalance
FROM userdetails1.UserTable t1
INNER JOIN userdetails2.AmountTable t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable investment
ON t1.Username = investment.Username
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable expenses
ON t1.Username = expenses.Username;
```

| UserID | TotalAmountResetDate | TotalAmount | Username | Totalnvested | TotalExpenses | TotalBalance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/31/2022 | -12 | John | 45000 | 2543 | 42445 |
| 2 | 1/31/2022 | 345 | Micheal | 45000 | 2345 | 43000 |
| 3 | 1/31/2022 | 213 | Ann | 45000 | 3290 | 41923 |
| 4 | 1/31/2022 | 0 | Shasha | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1/31/2022 | 0 | mike | 0 | 0 | 0 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uVe42xBgwEAnyAqvxCwJh9/1)

Comment: I am getting an syntax error in 12 and 14 lines

Comment: An alias was previously found. (near "t1" at position 394)

Comment: @Shehan There are some typos and missing `ON` keywords , now I fixed it

Comment: Thank you very much. I have upvoted your answer.  Can you update your question based on my updated answer as well? If i have more than one expenses or investments for each user we need to get the total of all investments and expenses to add to the table(As in the example for John new investment is 66000, not 45000). Then how we get the sum and group by with each user and get the required output?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101149/how-to-use-inner-joins-with-where-clause  can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

try like below using join and aggregation

```
    select ut.UserId,
ut.Username,
ua.TotalAmountResetDate,
sum(TotalAmount) as TotalAmount,
sum(Totalnvested) as TotalInvested,
sum(TotalExpenses) as TotalExpenses,
sum(TotalAmount+coalesce(Totalnvested ,0)- coalesce(TotalExpenses,0)) as TotalBalance

from userdetails1.UserTable ut 
left join
userdetails2.AmountTable ua on ut.UserId=ua.UserId

LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable env on
ut.Username = env.Username
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable ex
on ut.Username = ex.Username
group by ut.UserId,
ut.Username,
ua.TotalAmountResetDate
```

Comment: getting an syntax error, around this. 

LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable ex
ut.Username = ex.Username

Comment: @Shehan check now plz

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Joins command? Inner join, Full join?

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).