# How to use Inner Joins with where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am here posting some extension of [How to concatenate more sql queries to get one table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71098208/how-to-concatenate-more-sql-queries-to-get-one-table/71098266?noredirect=1#comment125682378_71098266) question to get more specific query results.

Let assume we are having now this type of dataset.

```
query1 : select * from userdetails1.UserTable;

Result1:                
UserID  Username    Status
1         John      Active
2         Micheal   Active
3         Ann       Active
4         Shasha    Resigned
5         mike      Resigned

query2 : 
select * 
from userdetails2.AmountTable 
where TotalAmountResetDate ='2022-01-31' ;

result2:
UserId  TotalAmount TotalAmountResetDate
1          -12         1/31/2022
2          345         1/31/2022
3          213         1/31/2022
4          0           1/31/2022
5          0           1/31/2022

query3:
select Username,sum(TotalInvested) as TotalInvested 
from userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable 
where total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
group by Username;

result3:

Username    Totalnvested
John         45000
Micheal      45000
Ann          45000

query4:
select Username,sum(TotalExpenses) 
from userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable 
where date_of_expense_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
group by Username;

Username    TotalExpenses
John           2543
Micheal        2345
Ann            3290
```

Then how I get the output as below,

```
UserId  Username    TotalAmountResetDate    TotalAmount Totalnvested    TotalExpenses   TotalBalance
1        John              1/31/2022               -12       45000            2543          42445
2        Micheal           1/31/2022               345       45000            2345          43000
3        Ann               1/31/2022               213       45000            3290          41923
4        Shasha            1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
5        mike              1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
```

From the answers I have made this answer, but seems it is not getting what I need, it removes Zero values. Can someone help?

```
    SELECT t2.UserID,
       t1.Username,
       t2.TotalAmountResetDate,   
       t2.TotalAmount,   
       COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) Totalnvested,
       COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalExpenses,
       t2.TotalAmount + COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) - COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalBalance
FROM userdetails1.UserTable t1
INNER JOIN userdetails2.AmountTable t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable investment
ON t1.Username = investment.Username
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable expenses
ON t1.Username = expenses.Username
where t2.TotalAmountResetDate='2022-01-31' and investment.total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12';
```

Comment: "it removes o values" Do you mean `0` or `NULL` values ?  If you mean `NULL` values, then the WHERE-clause is the problem, because you filter on `...and investment.total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'`. and there are probably no records with an `invested_date` between those dates that produce NULL values?

Comment: Yes. I mean NULL values. Yes. for some user there might be no expenses or no investments. So it removes all them I need to show them as it is by replacing Null with zero. I edited my question

Comment: No, it is not showing them because `investment.total_invested_date` will be NULL when there is no investment.   You should change `...and investment.total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'` to `...and (investment.total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12' or investment.total_invested_date IS NULL)`    ,and: " as it is by replacing Null with zero" this is done after fetching the data, in your WHERE-clause the value is still NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to let the condition move to `ON` from `WHERE` because you are doing `OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT t2.UserID,
       t1.Username,
       t2.TotalAmountResetDate,   
       t2.TotalAmount,   
       COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) Totalnvested,
       COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalExpenses,
       t2.TotalAmount + COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) - COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalBalance
FROM userdetails1.UserTable t1
INNER JOIN userdetails2.AmountTable t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable investment
ON t1.Username = investment.Username
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable expenses
ON t1.Username = expenses.Username AND 
investment.total_invested_date BETWEEN '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
WHERE t2.TotalAmountResetDate='2022-01-31';
```

Comment: This provides all the TotalAmountResetDate values. I only need the date as 2022-01-31

Comment: @Shehan Ok I see I edit my answer

Comment: I can see the total value of investments are wrong.It should be sum up by order by username.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108084/how-to-merge-two-sql-queries-and-get-output?noredirect=1#71108179  can you help here please?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, edited as I misread the question...

I would just move the date parameter from the where clause to the join on 'TotalInvestmentsTable' as below:

```sql
SELECT t2.UserID,
       t1.Username,
       t2.TotalAmountResetDate,   
       t2.TotalAmount,   
       COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) Totalnvested,
       COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalExpenses,
       t2.TotalAmount + COALESCE(Totalnvested,0) - COALESCE(TotalExpenses,0) TotalBalance
FROM userdetails1.UserTable t1
INNER JOIN userdetails2.AmountTable t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
INNER JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable investment
ON t1.Username = investment.Username
and investment.total_invested_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
INNER JOIN userdetails2.TotalExpensesTable expenses
ON t1.Username = expenses.Username
where t2.TotalAmountResetDate='2022-01-31';
```

Comment: OP says 'Then how I get the output as below,' and gives expected output in tabular form..

Comment: No.I dont need to omit. I want them as it is. As an example, Ann might not have invested on that period. But it should still show it as zero, and do not need to omit.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the section where you provided your expected result. I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply outer join the queries to your user table.

```
select
  u.username,
  a.totalamount,
  a.totalamountresetdate,
  coalesce(i.total, 0) as totalinvested,
  coalesce(e.total, 0) as totalexpenses,
  a.totalamount + coalesce(i.total, 0) - coalesce(e.total, 0) as totalbalance
from userdetails1.usertable u
left join userdetails2.amounttable a 
            on a.userid = u.userid
           and a.totalamountresetdate = date '2022-01-31'
left join
(
  select username, sum(totalinvested) as total 
  from userdetails2.totalinvestmentstable 
  where total_invested_date between date '2022-01-31' and date '2022-02-12'
  group by username
) i on i.username = u.username
left join
(
  select username, sum(totalexpenses) as total
  from userdetails2.totalexpensestable 
  where date_of_expense_date between date '2022-01-31' and date '2022-02-12'
  group by username
) e on e.username = u.username
order by u.username;
```

(It seems a bad idea by the way to use the username instead of the userid for the investment and expense tables. What do you have the userid for then?)