# How to merge two sql queries and get output?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am extending the [How to use Inner Joins with where clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71101149/how-to-use-inner-joins-with-where-clause) question because I need some extrnsion of this query results.

Here I have made a php script as below. This because a one table is in another server and it is not in same localhost. So I have created two different sql queries

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "project1";

$servername2 = "112.76.456.89";
$username2 = "user";
$password2 = "user990";
$dbname2= "project2";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create connection
$conn2 = mysqli_connect($servername2, $username2, $password2, $dbname2);
// Check connection
if (!$conn2) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql1 = "SELECT t2.UserID,
t1.Username,
t2.TotalAmountResetDate,   
t2.TotalAmount,   
sum(COALESCE(Totalnvested,0)) Totalnvested
FROM userdetails1.UserTable t1
INNER JOIN userdetails2.AmountTable t2
ON t1.UserID = t2.UserID
LEFT JOIN userdetails2.TotalInvestmentsTable investment
ON t1.Username = investment.Username AND 
investment.total_invested_date BETWEEN '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
WHERE t2.TotalAmountResetDate='2022-01-31' ";

$sql2="SELECT Username,sum(TotalExpenses) from TotalExpensesTable where date_of_expense_date between '2022-01-31' and '2022-02-12'
group by Username";


$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn2, $sql2);

mysqli_close($conn);
mysqli_close($conn2);
?>
```

From each sql query I can get the output as below.

Query1;

```
UserId  Username    TotalAmountResetDate    TotalAmount Totalnvested 
1        John              1/31/2022               -12       45000   
2        Micheal           1/31/2022               345       45000   
3        Ann               1/31/2022               213       45000   
4        Shasha            1/31/2022               0         0       
5        mike              1/31/2022               0         0
```

Query2:

```
Username    TotalExpenses
John           2543
Micheal        2345
Ann            3290
```

Now I need to get the output by combining these two as below,

```
UserId  Username    TotalAmountResetDate    TotalAmount Totalnvested    TotalExpenses   TotalBalance
1        John              1/31/2022               -12       45000            2543          42445
2        Micheal           1/31/2022               345       45000            2345          43000
3        Ann               1/31/2022               213       45000            3290          41923
4        Shasha            1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
5        mike              1/31/2022               0         0                 0            0
```

Can someone show me how should I get this kind of output using merging of above two queries? Do I need to use `foreach` loop?

I need to get UserId,Username,TotalAmountResetDate,TotalAmount,Totalnvested,TotalExpenses,TotalBalance then I can show it using a HTML table.

Comment: Are those valid credentials anyone can now use to connect to that server?

Comment: no.Just dummies.Cant connect

Comment: `$sql1`  your first quarry you get sum and not use group by my be it's give error.

Comment: Not sure this can be done in one query. Loop over your first dataset, add the data/calculations from the second dataset, output the result

Comment: Do you have `UserId` in `TotalExpensesTable`? If so, you don't even need to merge two query, just left join the TotalExpensesTable with userId with the first SQL.

Comment: @ikhvjs these are in two different servers.

Answer (score 0):

An example using `hashMap` to merge two datasets.

```php
<?php

$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($conn2, $sql2);

$res1 = mysqli_fetch_all($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$res2 = mysqli_fetch_all($result2, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$hashMapRes2 = array_reduce($res2, function ($carry, $item) {
    $username = $item['Username'];
    if (!isset($carry[$username])) {
        $carry[$username] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

$output = array_map(function ($item) use ($hashMapRes2) {
    $username = $item['Username'];
    if (isset($hashMapRes2[$username])) {
        $item['TotalExpenses'] = $hashMapRes2[$username]['TotalExpenses'];
    } else {
        $item['TotalExpenses'] = 0;
    }
    return $item;
}, $res1);

print_r($output);
```

[Sandbox Here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/959c005d94f3ecb54d321d8634f71ba7f5589103)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [UserId] => 1
            [Username] => John
            [TotalAmountResetDate ] => 1/31/2022
            [TotalAmount] => -12
            [Totalnvested] => 3055
            [TotalExpenses] => 11
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [UserId] => 1
            [Username] => Micheal
            [TotalAmountResetDate ] => 1/31/2022
            [TotalAmount] => 50
            [Totalnvested] => 3055
            [TotalExpenses] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [UserId] => 1
            [Username] => Shasha
            [TotalAmountResetDate ] => 1/31/2022
            [TotalAmount] => -12
            [Totalnvested] => 3055
            [TotalExpenses] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: But how to combine now these with sql qury data?

Comment: @Shehan The output is the combined data set. What do you need more?

Comment: You have manually added the data to array and performed. I need to fetch all them using the query. Not the dummy typed data.

Comment: @Shehan, I updated my answer. You can use `mysqli_fetch_all($result1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` to fetch all data from a result.